# \newcommand, 1 optional argument, no mandatory arguments

Tags: macros

I am trying to write a function which takes only one optional argument. How do I do this with `\newcommand`?

Here is my attempt:

```
\newcommand{\s}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{S(\Theta)}{S^{#1}(\Theta)}%
}
```

but it fails when I don't specify the argument.

edit: `\newcommand{\s}[1][]` does not work, as then the output is not as desired:

```
\s{2} -> S(Theta)2
```

Comment: Add the default value of the optional argument to tell LaTeX that it is optional: `\newcommand{\s}[1][]{...}`

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I edited my answer to solve the problem you stated in your edit. Next time, leave a comment instead. People don't get notified of edits. You were lucky the edit fell in my review queue.

Comment: With an optional argument, the syntax is `\s[2]` with square brackets.  Then, the optional argument works as desired (i.e., producing `S^2(\Theta}`).

Answer (score 2):

## Edit:

In your edit you said:

> edit: `\newcommand{\s}[1][]` does not work, as then the output is not as desired:
>
> ```
> \s{2} -> S(Theta)2
> ```

So your definition of the command `\s` is incorrect. I propose you use this definition of `\s`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\s}{o}{%
  S(\Theta)\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
  $\s$

  $\s[2]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `xparse` to define the command and, as egreg suggested in the comments, using `\IfValueT` to check the presence of the optional argument and write the superscript.

You have to call `\s[2]`, though. Defining an optional argument delimited by braces it not a good idea.

## My previous answer:

You must add a default value to tell LaTeX that the argument is optional, like this:

```
%                 ↓ default value to the optional argument
\newcommand{\s}[1][]{...}
```

Or you could use `xparse` to have more control over the arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{ifthen}

% "usual" way
\newcommand{\s}[1][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{S(\Theta)}{S^{#1}(\Theta)}%
}

% Exactly the same as above. The O{} tells xparse that the first argument
% is optional and the default value is empty
\NewDocumentCommand{\xxs}{O{}}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{S(\Theta)}{S^{#1}(\Theta)}%
}

% This one also tells xparse that the first argument is optional, but
% the presence of the optional argument can be tested with \IfNoValueTF
\NewDocumentCommand{\xs}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
  {S(\Theta)}%
  {S^{#1}(\Theta)}%
}

\begin{document}
  $\s$

  $\s[a]$

  $\xxs$

  $\xxs[a]$

  $\xs$

  $\xs[a]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The last example is not good, because an empty superscript triggers the insertion of `\scriptspace`. The second example can be written more compactly: `S\IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}(\Theta)`

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I noticed the empty superscript later. I didn't know about `\IfValueT`. Many thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using `\@ifnextchar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \makeatletter
    \newcommand\@s{S(\theta)}
    \newcommand\s@opt[1]{S^{#1}(\theta)}
    \newcommand\s{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\s@opt\@s}
  \makeatother
  \[ \s\s{2} \]
\end{document}
```

Whats going on here is that when you do `\s`, then `\@ifnextchar` checks the next character.

If it is an opening bracket (or any `\bgroup`), then it executes `\s@opt`, if not it executes `\@s`. `\s@opt` expects one argument, but `\@s`does not.

That is: if the next character is a `\bgroup` (opening brace*) then LaTeX replaces `\s` with the `\s@opt`, else with the `\@s`.

---

### Below this point at your own risk.

---

#### Down the rabbit hole we go:

You can do even more fancy stuff here, like make `\s^{2}` -> `S^{2}(\theta)` like so**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \makeatletter
    \newcommand\@s{S(\theta)}
    \def\s@pow^#1{S^{#1}(\theta)}
    \newcommand\s{\@ifnextchar^\s@pow\@s}
  \makeatother
  \[ \s \]     %<- prints S(\theta)
  \[ \s^{2} \] %<- prints S^2(\theta)
\end{document}
```

OR you could do an optional squaring, like `\s{\theta}^{2}` -> `S^{2}(\theta)` whilst `\s{\theta}` -> `S(\theta)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \makeatletter
    \def\s#1{\def\res@a{#1}\@ifnextchar^\s@pow\@s}
    \def\@s{S(\res@a)}
    \def\s@pow^#1{S^{#1}(\res@a)}
  \makeatother
  \[ \s{\theta} \]    %<- S(\theta)
  \[ \s{\theta}^{2} \]%<- S^{2}(\theta)
\end{document}
```

---

*:unless otherwise defined, which it's usually not.

**: This is probably not recommended because of some reasons. I do not know these reasons, but I feel like I'm doing something hacky?